# How to populate custom header/footer view when using RxDatasources for datasource

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, rx-swift, rx-cocoa

I am using `RxDatasources` to create my datasource. Later on, I configure cells in my view controller. The thing is, cause headers/footers has nothing with datasource (except we can set a title, but if we use custom header footer, this title will be overriden).

Now, this is how I configure my tableview cells:

```
private func observeDatasource(){
    
    let dataSource = RxTableViewSectionedAnimatedDataSource<ConfigStatusSectionModel>(
        configureCell: { dataSource, tableView, indexPath, item in
            if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: ConfigItemTableViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as? BaseTableViewCell{
                cell.setup(data: item.model)
                return cell
            }

            return UITableViewCell()
        })
    
    botConfigViewModel.sections
        .bind(to: tableView.rx.items(dataSource: dataSource))
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)  
}
```

now cause

```
dataSource.titleForHeaderInSection = { dataSource, index in
            return dataSource.sectionModels[index].model
}
```

... won't work, cause I want to load a custom header and populate it with data from `RxDatasource`, I wonder what would be a proper way to:

- get data from my datasource which is defined in my view model
- populate header, based on a section (I have multiple sections) with correct data, in the way that is always up to date with a datasource.

Here is my view model:

```
 class ConfigViewModel{
        
        private let disposeBag = DisposeBag()
        let sections:BehaviorSubject<[ConfigStatusSectionModel]> = BehaviorSubject(value: [])
        
        func startObserving(){
            
            let observable = getDefaults()
            
            observable.map { conditions -> [ConfigStatusSectionModel] in
                return self.createDatasource(with: conditions)
            }.bind(to: self.sections).disposed(by: disposeBag)
        }
        
        private func getDefaults()->Observable<ConfigDefaultConditionsModel> {
            
            return Observable.create { observer in
                FirebaseManager.shared.getConfigDefaults { conditions in
                  
                    observer.onNext(conditions!)
    
                } failure: { error in
                    observer.onError(error!)
                }
                return Disposables.create()
            }
        }
        
        private func createDatasource(with defaults:ConfigDefaultConditionsModel)->[ConfigStatusSectionModel]{
            
        
            let firstSectionItems = defaults.start.elements.map{ConfigItemModel(item: $0, data: nil)}
            let firstSection = ConfigStatusSectionModel(model: defaults.start.title, items: firstSectionItems.compactMap{ConfigCellModel(model: $0)})
            
            let secondSectionItems = defaults.stop.elements.map{ConfigItemModel(item: $0, data: nil)}
            let secondSection = ConfigStatusSectionModel(model: defaults.stop.title, items: secondSectionItems.compactMap{ConfigCellModel(model: $0)})
            
            let sections:[ConfigStatusSectionModel] = [firstSection, secondSection]
            
            return sections
        }
    }
```

Now what I was able to do, is to set a tableview delegate, like this:

```
tableView.rx.setDelegate(self).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

and then to implement appropriate delegate method(s) to create / return custom header:

```
extension BotConfigViewController: UITableViewDelegate {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                   viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        guard let header = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(
                            withIdentifier: ConfigSectionTableViewHeader.identifier)
                            as? ConfigSectionTableViewHeader
        else {
            return nil
        }
        return header
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableView.automaticDimension
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 40
    }
  
}
```

How to populate my custom header with data from my datasource? I don't want to do things like `switch (section){...}`, cause then its completely not in sync with a datasource, but rather manually, and if datasource changes, it won't affect on header configuration automatically.

Here are my model structs:

```
typealias ConfigStatusSectionModel = AnimatableSectionModel<String, ConfigCellModel>

struct ConfigItemData {
    let conditionsLink:String?
    let iconPath:String?
}

struct ConfigItemModel {
    
    let item:OrderConditionModel
    let data:ConfigItemData?
}

struct ConfigCellModel : Equatable, IdentifiableType {
    
    static func == (lhs: ConfigCellModel, rhs: ConfigCellModel) -> Bool {
        
        return lhs.model.item.symbol == rhs.model.item.symbol
    }
    var identity: String {
        return model.item.symbol
    }
    let model: ConfigItemModel
}
```

I tried to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70503608/how-to-provide-custom-header-footer-to-a-tableview-using-rxdatasources) but I wasn't able to make it work completely, cause I guess I wasn't providing custom header in a right way/moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fundamental issue here is that `tableView(_:viewForHeaderInSection:)` is a pull based method and Rx is designed for push based systems. Obviously it can be done. After all, the base library did it for `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)` but it's quite a bit more complex. You can follow the same system that the base library uses for the latter function.

Below is such a system. It can be used like this:

```
source
    .bind(to: tableView.rx.viewForHeaderInSection(
        identifier: ConfigSectionTableViewHeader.identifier,
        viewType: ConfigSectionTableViewHeader.self
    )) { section, element, view in
        view.setup(data: element.model)
    }
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Here is the code that makes the above possible:

```
extension Reactive where Base: UITableView {
    func viewForHeaderInSection<Sequence: Swift.Sequence, View: UITableViewHeaderFooterView, Source: ObservableType>
    (identifier: String, viewType: View.Type = View.self)
    -> (_ source: Source)
    -> (_ configure: @escaping (Int, Sequence.Element, View) -> Void)
    -> Disposable
    where Source.Element == Sequence {
        { source in
            { builder in
                let delegate = RxTableViewDelegate<Sequence, View>(identifier: identifier, builder: builder)
                base.rx.delegate.setForwardToDelegate(delegate, retainDelegate: false)
                return source
                    .concat(Observable.never())
                    .subscribe(onNext: { [weak base] elements in
                        delegate.pushElements(elements)
                        base?.reloadData()
                    })
            }
        }
    }
}

final class RxTableViewDelegate<Sequence, View: UITableViewHeaderFooterView>: NSObject, UITableViewDelegate where Sequence: Swift.Sequence {
    let build: (Int, Sequence.Element, View) -> Void
    let identifier: String
    private var elements: [Sequence.Element] = []

    init(identifier: String, builder: @escaping (Int, Sequence.Element, View) -> Void) {
        self.identifier = identifier
        self.build = builder
    }

    func pushElements(_ elements: Sequence) {
        self.elements = Array(elements)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        guard let view = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: identifier) as? View else { return nil }
        build(section, elements[section], view)
        return view
    }
}
```

Comment: Yup, this totally worked. I just had to add `guard !elements.isEmpty, let view = ...` to prevent crash when elements are empty. It shame that there is no option to award additionally answers. But at least I can say, thanks a bunch!

Comment: FYI, I made a minor update. It turns out that RxCocoa installs its own delegate even if you don't explicitly do it. So I modified the code to install this new delegate as a `forwardToDelegate`.

Answer (score 0):

Daniel T.'s answer works fine in Swift 5 as well.
However, in my case, a crash occurred when there was empty data.

So I added a `guard else` to return the header view so that it is not visible when the elements are empty.

If you want to see an empty header view, just return view instead of nil.
I hope this helps.

```swift
final class RxTableViewDelegate<Sequence, View: UITableViewHeaderFooterView>: NSObject, UITableViewDelegate where Sequence: Swift.Sequence {
  //...

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    guard let view = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: identifier) as? View else { return nil }
    guard elements.isEmpty == false else { return nil } //<- Here
    build(section, elements[section], view)
    return view
  }
}
```